# 2026, SSL connection error: unknown error number - encountered by my django app after upgrading mysql from 5 to 8

Tags: mysql, django, ssl, mysql-8.0

I upgraded mysql from 5.7 to 8.0 and started encountering this error which is preventing my app from connecting to the database.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: unknown error number')
```

I have my own ca.pem server-cert.pem server-key.pem which mysql uses. The django app properly sets the ca cert in settings. Everything works in 5.7.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue when running ‘python manage.py showmigrations’ from my Django project to a remote MySQL server. I’m using Django 3.1.7 and MySQL 8.0.

The below steps worked in my case:

1. Install PyMySql

   In **init**.py (under the same directory as settings.py), add the following code:

   ```
    import pymysql
    pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
   ```

Answer (score 1):

1. Try upgrading your django app's OS. I upgraded my docker image base from `slim-stretch` to `slim-buster` and the error went away
2. in your mysql config file, try adding this under `mysqld`

```
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
```

3. Remove `ssl` from the django database settings (`DATABASES['OPTIONS']['ssl']`) and see if the error goes away